# Cannot add environment variable to pom.xml file with groovy

Tags: xml, maven, groovy

I have 4 environments named `dev`, `sit`, `uat` and `prod`. I need update below tag with this value. `$environments` refers to the environment name.

```
<am.userName>'${env.AM_$environments.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}'</am.userName>
```

But this returns an error as,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project basic-wso2-archetype:
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'it-basic' failed: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Encountered "$environments" at archetype-resources/pom.xml[line 179, column 32]
[ERROR] Was expecting one of:
[ERROR]     "[" ...
[ERROR]     "}" ...
[ERROR]
```

As a workaround I tried to do this with a groovy script as below, with a placeholder as `AM_SERVER_CREDS_USR` to replace the value.

```
def mainPomXml = new File(rootDir, '/pom.xml')
def mainPom = mainPomXml.text.replace('AM_SERVER_CREDS_USR', '${env.AM_'+ env.toUpperCase() +'_SERVER_CREDS_USR}')
mainPomXml.write(mainPom)
```

But instead of looping the environments, it changes all the `AM_SERVER_CREDS_USR` with the first value of the loop.

How to make any of the above methods work? or is there any other method to do this task?

Comment: The loop you are talking about is not shown in your code. Please provide the full example or even better a minimal example that just shows the problem (e.g. the problem is most likely maven-agnostic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to the first `$` here,

```
<am.userName>'${env.AM_$environments.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}'</am.userName>
```

So, define the dollar as a variable in the XML file.

```
#set( $dollar = '$' )
```

Now refer the dollar variable in the XML.

```
<am.userName>${dollar}{env.AM_$environment.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}</am.userName>
```